# Hibernate ORM without XML

Tags: java, hibernate

I have used EclipseLink till now, but now I'm trying a Java SE project with Hibernate 4. I'm trying to do perform a NamedQuery but I get the following exception:

```
HibernateLog --> 18:05:03 ERROR org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl - HHH000177: Error in named query: SubCategory.findAll
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Subcategory is not mapped [SELECT s from Subcategory s]
```

This is my DBUtils class

```
public class DBUtils {

    static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DBUtils.class);

    private static final ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    /**
     * 
     */
      //initialize session factory;

      static {
          try {
              Configuration conf = new Configuration()
                // mapped classes; 
                .addAnnotatedClass(Category.class)
                .addAnnotatedClass(SubCategory.class)
                .configure();

                             //.....

              serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(conf.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
              sessionFactory = conf.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
          } catch (Throwable ex) {
              logger.error("Initial SessionFactory creation failed");
              System.err.println("." + ex);
              throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
          }
      }


      public static synchronized SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
          return sessionFactory;
      }
}
```

And this is my hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
                <!-- Ommitted... -->

        <!-- JDBC connection pool, use Hibernate internal connection pool -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">5</property>


        <!-- Defines the SQL dialect used in Hibernate application -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</property>


        <!-- hibernate sql output -->
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>
        <property name="format_sql">false</property>
        <property name="use_sql_comments">false</property>

        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet">utf8</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Finally my entities are all annotated with `@Entity("tableName"`) annotation

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate is case sensitive and uses the class name to map an Entity in its HQL. So

```
SELECT s from Subcategory s
```

will refer to an entity class called `Subcategory`. This is wrong. Use the actual class name

```
SELECT s from SubCategory s
```

as your class is named `SubCategory`, seen in

```
.addAnnotatedClass(SubCategory.class)
```

Comment: Right, thats what happens when I dont use autocomplete!

Comment: @ChrisGeo I don't think you can use autocomplete in Strings. :)

Comment: In Eclipse if you work on a faceted project with JPA, it supports JPQL autocomplete when constructing @NamedQueries (in the actual String). So you get popups with all the classes-entities and also their members. In this case where it was a pure Java SE project there was no support though ;).